# Bootstrap dialog doesn't show on "xs" screen

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

On a Bootstrap 3 site I have a dialog box. It always opens when its associated button is clicked. However, I would also like it to open when called by a certain function in Javascript:

```
$('#login').modal('show');
```

This code works on most screens, but doesn't work on mobile devices (screen size 'xs'). I can't work out why. Here is a minimal(ish) reproduction - resize the preview pane and reload to see what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/u7KW6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seem to appear because you placed your `modal div` inside your `navbar-header`. If you move it outside that div like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/bbP2y/) example, it will work as you wish.